# Rendering an animation only returns blank images

Tags: rendering, animation

I am having trouble rendering my animation

When I click `Render animation` it will give me 40 blank images. The frames are all correct. I think I messed around with the settings too much.

I am quite new to blender, also I'm  using blender 2.79. Here's the file.

[image]

Comment: is this in video editing preset?

Comment: no, I dont think it is.

Comment: have you changed the audio settings or it is set to no audio

Comment: I didn't mess around with the audio settings so no

Comment: have you done anything in the video sequencer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing a strip from the Video Editor.

[image]